# Dropdown multiselect - Events triggering all time

Tags: angularjs

I am using the Angular dropdown multi select module.
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

And I use its events feature but it gets triggered all time even when I click any where else other than the drop down.

**Plunkr :**

http://plnkr.co/edit/hlsaiG?p=preview

**Javascript**

```
var jayApp = angular.module('jayApp',['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

jayApp.controller('jayController', function($scope) {

    $scope.example1model = []; 
    $scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];


    // MultiSelect Drop down select - Event
    $scope.onItemSelect = function(property) {
    console.log('selecting > ' +property);
    }

    $scope.onItemDeselect = function(property) {
    console.log('deselecting : ' +property);
    }

})
```

**HTML**

Drop down :

```
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model" events="onItemSelect(example1model); onItemDeselect(example1model)">

    </div>
  <br>
  User <input type='text' name='dummy'> <br><br>
  Password <input type='password' name='pass'> <br><br>

  <input type='submit'>

</body>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in the Plunkr, using latest Chrome on Mac... What is the expected behaviour ? What is "triggered all time"?

Comment: @Bonatoc Thanks. I do not want the event to be triggered other than the select drop-down component. But currently it triggers even if you click the mouse any where else.. You can verify that using the console logs in browser using F12 key.

Answer (score 4):

The events attribute of directive ng-dropdown-multiselect expects a JS object,
instead of 
`events="onItemSelect(example1model); onItemDeselect(example1model)"`.
See the full solution in this Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lsaLqUYm4haN1qdR6Omt?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Nico, for example. It helps me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it indeed works like that. I believe **it smells**, but that's how it is.
Now, is that really a problem for you? You can still probably work with this as it is. Although, I'd recommend creating an **issue** ticket on their GitHub project.

On the other hand, you're probably expecting this to work like an `onChange` event. You might be glad to know that there currently is a **pending PULL request** for actually adding a support for `onChange` event in **AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect**: here's a [link to the pull request](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/pull/43) I'm talking about.

If you can't wait for this feature to be merged, just check out the **Master** branch on [PawelDecowski's forked project (link)](https://github.com/PawelDecowski/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect).

Answer (score 0):

You can inline it like this

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect
     options="regions_options"
     selected-model="regions_selected"
     events="{ onItemSelect: someFunction }">
```

or even have multiple callbacks inline by extending the events object, like so:

```
events="{ onItemSelect: someFunction, onInitDone: functionToBeExecutedOnInitDone }"
```

Notice that we are referencing the function, not calling it. someFunction - without ().